# Switch to another App when call is coming

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I want to call my own BB Hello World application when a call is coming on the device.. for this i have used AbstractPhoneListner and override its method also ...

```
public class MyListner extends AbstractPhoneListener {

HelloBlackBerryScreen obj;

    public MyListner() {

}

        public void callIncoming(int callId) {

            super.callIncoming(callId);
            try {
                  ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launchApplication("Helloworld");
                } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Now, when i tried this on simulator , it is not working . what else should i do ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Register the phone listener when your application start. Like this.

```
 public MyListner() {

       Phone.addListener(this);

}
```